# Does an object always see its latest internal state irrespective of thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Let's say I have a runnable with a simple integer count variable which is incremented every time runnable runs. One instance of this object is submitted to run periodically in a scheduled executor service.

```
class Counter implements Runnable {
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
      count++;
    }
}

Counter counter = new Counter();
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(counter, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here, the object is accessing its own internal state inside of different threads (reading and incrementing). Is this code thread-safe or is it possible that we lose updates to the `count` variable when it's scheduled in a different thread?

Comment: Nope; most definitely not.

Comment: Just to be clear: When the answers below say "...no happens-before..." what they're saying is, Suppose `count==N`. Then along comes worker thread A, which sets `count = N+1`.  Then one whole second later, worker thread B is chosen to call the `run()` method, and worker thread B looks at `count`.  It is possible at that point for worker thread B to still see `count == N`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Does an object always see its latest internal state irrespective of thread?*

Just to be clear for the purposes of this question and its answers, an object doesn't *do* anything; it's just memory. Threads are the executing entity. It's misleading to say *does an object see whatever*. It's the thread that's doing the *seeing/reading* of object state.

This isn't specified in the javadoc, but

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
```

returns a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Your code is using

```
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(counter, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The [javadoc for `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduledWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) states

> Submits a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given
>   initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay between the
>   termination of one execution and the commencement of the next.

The class [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) further clarifies

> Successive executions of a periodic task scheduled via
>   `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay` do not overlap.
>   **While different executions may be performed by different threads, the
>   effects of prior executions happen-before those of subsequent ones**.

As such, each execution of `Counter#run` is guaranteed to see the value of `count` after it's been incremented by the previous execution. For example, the third execution will read a `count` value of `2` before it performs its increment.

You don't need `volatile` or any other additional synchronization mechanism for *this specific use case*.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this happens-before guarantee about  `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 7):

No, this code is not thread-safe because there isn't any *happens-before* relation between increments made in different threads started with `ScheduledExecutorService`.

To fix it, you need to either mark the variable as `volatile` or switch to `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong`.

UPDATE:

As @BoristheSpider mentioned, in general in case of increment/decrement making a variable `volatile` is not enough since increment/decrement is not atomic itself and calling it from several threads concurrently will cause race conditions and missed updates. However, in this particular case `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` guarantees (according to Javadoc) that there will be overlapping executions of scheduled task, so `volatile` will also work **in this particular case** even with increment.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  taking into account how `scheduleWithFixedDelay` work there will be no overlapped calls to `counter++` in that particular scenario. So `volatile` should be OK.

Comment: There is a happens-before relation introduced between subsequent execution of a task scheduled with `scheduleWithFixedDelay`.

Comment: How come `volatile` is not enough? The semantics of `volatile` should hold in every case and it would solve this problem. In the past, the writing of doubles and longs could have been more difficult to do atomically since those occupied more than one 32-bit register. However, as far as I can tell, that should not affect the semantics of volatile. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo in this particular case `volatile` is enough. But in general case not because increment is effectively translated into 3 operations: read, add, write and is prone to race condition in multithreaded environment

Comment: To reiterate, the code they have posted is thread-safe. This answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, this code is not thread-safe since there isn't any *[happens before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)* relation between different threads accessing `count`.

Comment: @michid please correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't `counter++` be synchronized too as increment operation is not **atomic**.

Comment: Does `counter++` need to be synchronized even if it's guaranteed that only one thread will be running this runnable at a time (like in the code in the question)?

Comment: @RandomQuestion yes. Because visibility.

Comment: I agree with the comments here that accesses to `counter++` should be synchronized and that merely declaring it volatile is not sufficient. I edited my answer accordingly focusing on the happens-before relation.

Comment: There actually is a happens-before relation between executions of the task.

Comment: @RandomQuestion To reiterate, the code you have posted is thread-safe. This answer is wrong.